# How to get value json into textbox [xamarin] using restSharp

Tags: xamarin

i'm the new in xamarin programming, 
i want to ask, how to parsing json into textbox in the xamarin android..

```
  var MyEntry = new Entry { Placeholder = "SPAT" };
        MyEntry.TextColor = Color.White;

        var client = new RestClient("http://rest-service.guides.spring.io");
        var request = new RestRequest("greeting", Method.GET);
        IRestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
        var content = response.Content;
        MyEntry.Text = content;
```

and this the json

```
{"id":297,"content":"Hello, World!"}
```

Comment: Use newtonsoft json to parse response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Restsharp offers deserialization out of the box. Just create a class that maps your json.

```cs
public class MyModel
{
    public int Id {get; set;}
    public string Content {get; set;}
}
```

And then use `Execute<T>` instead of `Execute`.

```cs
var response = client.Execute<MyModel>(request);
var model = response.Data;
```

And then you can set the text easily:

```cs
MyEntry.Text = model.Content;
```

For more information read:

- [Recommended Usage](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Recommended-Usage)
- [Deserialization](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/Deserialization)